# MySQL display a sum as a column

Tags: mysql

There are 2 tables customer (id, name) and orders (id, customer_id, date, price) where customer_id is the foreign key.

How would one get the top 5 individuals with the most purchases in the last 6 months?

needed output format is (customer.id, customer.name, sum(price))

```
select c.id, c.name, SUM(o.price) as total
from customer c inner join orders o 
on c.id = o.customer_id
order by total desc limit 5;
```

I'm not sure why this query I have doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

SUM() is an aggregate function that calculates the sum after a grouping operation. Try using a `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
select c.id, c.name, SUM(o.price) as total
from customer c inner join orders o 
on c.id = o.customer_id
group by c.id, c.name
order by total desc limit 5;
```

DB-fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7f5e3726d6af5a9144a03d503da5ae37